# Importing NPM packages

Tags: azure-devops, npm-package, proget

We have a ProGet server where we store nuget and npm packages developed in our company.
Each npm package is stored in tgz file on the ProGet server. We want to move them to Azure DevOps artifacts (the server is on-prem in case it matters) and stop using the ProGet server. How can I import them all?